# Getting invisible values in dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wanted to have multiple values in a dropdown list using javascript so that there is no need to write much values in the option of the select tag, so I used the code below to do so but it is showing invisible values when opened in internet explorer means allocated space is visible but not the content, in chrome & firefox it shows nothing.

```
  <script>
    function Time(){
        selectHr();
        selectMin();
        selectSec();
     }

     function selectHr()
        {  
           for(var x=1;x<=24;x++)
              {
                var option = document.createElement("option");
                option.text = x;
                option.value=x;
                document.getElementById('dateTime_selHr').add(option);   
             } 
        }
      function selectMin()
         {  
             for(var x=1;x<=60;x++)
                {
                  var option = document.createElement("option");
                   option.text = x;
                   option.value=x;
                    document.getElementById('dateTime_selMin').add(option);   
                } 
          }    

      function selectSec()
        {  
           for(var x=1;x<=60;x++)
              {
                  var option = document.createElement("option");
                  option.text = x;
                  option.value=x;
                  document.getElementById('dateTime_selSec').add(option);   
              } 
        }

    </script>
    </head>

   <body onload="Time()">
     <table class="table" id="dateTime_tbl">
         <tr>
         <td>
                Camera&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                </td>
            <td colspan="2">
                 <input type="text" name="camera" />
           </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
            <td>
            Time In Camera Date
            </td>
            <td>
            Date &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="date"/>
            Time&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="text" name="time" />
            </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td> Set Time</td>
          <td>
         <input type="radio" />  Set manually
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td></td>
          <td>Date&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="text"  name="txtdate"          />            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          Time &nbsp;&nbsp;
           hr : <span> <select name="hr" id="dateTime_selHr">      </select>            </span>    
           min :  <span> <select name="min" id="dateTime_selMin" > </select> </span>     
           sec :   <span> <select name="sec" id="dateTime_selSec" > </select> </span>  

          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td></td>
           <td>
               <input type="radio" name="syncTime" />Synchronize with computer time
           </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td></td>
             <td>
                Date&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="text" /> 
                  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  Time&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" />
               </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td></td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" />  Synchronize with SNTP server
            </td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td></td>
            <td>
                SNTP Server&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="text" style="width:200px"/>
            </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td></td>
            <td>
              Time Zone&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <span> <select name="timeZone">
                      <option></option>
                </select></span>
            </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
            <td></td>
             <td>
                  <input type="checkbox" />  Automatically adjust for daylight saving time changes
             </td>

      </tr>
      <tr>

            <td>
                Date Format &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <span><select>
                      <option>-select-</option>
                       <option>YYYY/MM/DD</option>
                        <option>MM/DD/YYYY</option>
                         <option>DD/MM/YYYY</option>
                 </select></span>
            </td>

            <td> 
                 Time Format&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <span> <select>
                       <option>-select-</option>
                        <option>12 hour format</option>
                         <option>24 hour format</option>
                          <option>DD/MM/YYYY</option>
                  </select></span>
            </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>

            <td>
            Date Position&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span><select>
                  <option>-select-</option>
                        <option>Bottom Left</option>
                         <option>Bottom Right</option> 
            </select></span>
            </td>

            <td>
              Time Position&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span> <select>
                   <option>-select-</option>
                        <option>Bottom Left</option>
                         <option>Bottom Right</option> 
               </select></span>
            </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <center>
      <div id="dateTime_actionBtnsDiv">
          <button type="button" name="ok" style="width:80px"          id="dtTime_btns">OK</button>
   <button type="button" name="cancel" style="width:80px" id="dtTime_btns">CANCEL</button>
   </div>
     </center>
     </body>
```

Can anybody help me in resolving this?

Comment: Can you let us know what do you mean by `invisible values`?

Comment: I have tested your code. it seems to be working fine. what error are you getting ?

Comment: @SpiderCode in IE 9 for me, it is displaying the error OP states: http://fiddle.jshell.net/tR2GC/show/

Answer (score 2):

You can use add() function instead

```
function selectFunction()
       {  
           for(var x=1;x<=5;x++)
          {
               var option = document.createElement("option");
               option.text = x;
               option.value=x;
               document.getElementById('selectId').add(option);   
          } 
       }
```

Comment: Please check the answer if the above solution is able to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

This Worked Fine and Tested in IE.

```
<script>
        function selectFunction()
             {  
               var selector = document.getElementById('selectId');   
               for(var x=1;x<=5;x++)
                  {
                     var opt  = document.createElement('option');
                     opt.value     = x;
                     opt.innerHTML = x;
                     selector.appendChild(opt);  
                   } 
             }   
       </script>

       <body onload="selectFunction()">
           <select id="selectId"></select>
       </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is bug registered with Microsoft
[You can check it here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/276228)

so instead of using ur code ,i recommend

```
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.text = x;
option.value=x;
document.getElementById('selectId').add(option);
```